# Weird vertices on subsurf modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I used edge loops, and then while cleaning up, I had to delete some vertices (dissolved) and then joined them again using faces. Now when i use subsurf modifier, when mesh looks weird. Fairly new and going through a tutorial to create a face model. If someone can point me in the right direction, will appreciate it.

1. Subsurf Off

[image]

2. Subsurf On

   [image]

Comment: You have at least one NGon on your mesh (face with more than 4 vertex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to faces with more than 4 vertices as the subsurf can only work with triangles (3 vertices) and quads (4 vertices).

Faces with more than 4 vertices are known as 'ngons' (basically 'polygon' with with the 'poly' replaced with 'n' to represent any number (*greater than 4*) - I can see two towards the top-centre of your image and it is those that are causing the issue.

The solution is to adjust the geometry to replace those faces with tri and quad faces. The easiest way to achieve this would be to simply cut one of the corners off to a tri, leaving a quad.

Comment: Thanks, that helped solve my problem. Quick question though, to select all such non-manifolds, I pressed Ctrl-Shft-Alt-M. That gave me all the problematic edges/vertices, but also said that the open holes in the mesh as well as the central edge line on which the mesh is mirrored is also non-manifold, though it has no deformity at all and looks good after applying the subsurf. Is that normal?

Comment: @Ratan I think you’re confusing the meaning of non-manifold. The faces with more than 4 vertices are ngons, while ‘manifold’ refers to whether that mesh defines a single enclosed volume - two different things. The non-manifolds shortcut will select the unbound edges. To select the Ngons you can use a different function - Select Faces By Sides - which allows you to select all faces with more than a specified number of edges.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I think I got confused as ngons and some of those non-manifolds were having the same messed up affect on my mesh after the subsurf. That explains it, thanks!